# Connection pool configuration with Jedis MultiClusterPooledConnectionProvider

Tags: jedis, failover

I want to use MultiClusterPooledConnectionProvider to leverage failover feature of Jedis.

```
UnifiedJedis jedis = new UnifiedJedis(multiClusterPooledConnectionProvider);
```

How can I provide custom GenericObjectPoolConfig for MultiClusterPooledConnectionProvider? This class does not have constructor/setters to configure pool properties.